# Get custom category attribute in Navigation Tree

Tags: magento2

I have created a new category custom attribute. It works fine, the attribute is saved when I save the category.

I'd like to use this attribute in the navigation tree logic so that I can apply some changes to the tree depending on its value.

The problem is that I can't access this attribute value from here: Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu (using a preference, of course). The point is that I need to edit the html markup, but the $child elements in there don't contain this category data.

How can I add that category attribute data to the nodes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Default magento menu render from `Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu`.
This class is plugin class of `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu`.

If you want to customized then you have to work on this class.

First you have to add your custom attribute to collection of tree mean
`\Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu::getCategoryTree`.

Have to add field your field  `collection->addAttributeToSelect('{YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE}');` like `collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');` then you can access that attribute to desire function of that class.

Answer (score 0):

create etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\CategoryCustomAttribute" />
</config>
```

**then create CategoryCustomAttribute.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

class CategoryCustomAttribute extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
{
    public function getCatgCustomAttribute()
    {            
        return $this->getCustomAttribute('your_attribute_code'); // pass your attribute code here           
    }
}
```

then just call this function `getCatgCustomAttribute()`in your template.